# What material are Velux FSCC room darkening solar blinds made out of?

Tags: materials, blinds, skylight

I had some new skylights installed, which included the installation of some double-pleated Velux solar blinds. I'm pretty sure the Velux website says that all of their blinds are made out of fabric, but now that I've gotten up and taken a close look at the blinds, I'm fairly sure they're actually paper. Is this right?

Comment: we have no way of telling if your blinds are made out of paper ... ask someone to verify your opinion

Comment: Yeah, they're paper. I thought they were supposed to he fabric, but now I'm second guessing myself. Does Velux make paper blinds? I'm wondering if my contractor installed a cheap knock-off, or if I just misunderstood the materials I was expecting.

Comment: contact the company

Answer (score 1):

Many people say tyvek looks like paper. Fabric is woven paper is usually not It depends on the process. There are types of woven cellulose blinds same fibers as paper but since they are woven it is a fabric. I believe this slight difference is what is causing the confusion.